# Alter exteral table everyday in Hive

Tags: hive, alter-table

I have an external table in hive that I want to alter its location everyday.
I want to do somethong like below **in hive script** directly:

```
 set current_day = from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(), 'yyyy_mm_dd');
 ALTER TABLE myTable ADD PARTITION (dt=${hiveconf:current_day})
 LOCATION concat('s3://.../',${hiveconf:current_day});
```

Could you please show me the correct scripts in Hive?

Bests,

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this python [script](https://github.com/don9z/hadoop-tools/blob/master/hive/addpartition.py)
It should create a new partition for the external table each time a new folder is created under the root location of the external table.

If the script doesn't match your needs you can always write a quick bash script that accepts a date in the correct string format and executes :

```
hive -e "use myDB; alter table myTable add partition ($SOMEDATE);"
```

Then, you can add this script to `crontab` and execute it on a daily basis.